# Uncaught SyntaxError: missing, ) after argument list

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

im bulding a search box for movies using an API
any time onkeyup event takes place a function is called which in turn prepare an ajax and display the responsed json in  li tags.
of course it displays 20 results i want to be able to store the result the user clicked on and displayed on div id="target"
here is my code:

http://jsfiddle.net/bkj2z39y/

every thing is working except the clicking

```
 function func(str) {

 $('#here').html('');
 document.getElementById("here").style.border = "0px";
 $('#movie').val('');
 alert(str);

    $('#target').html(str);
      console.log(str);

      }
```

i have tried several methods, this last one gives me an error

Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

Comment: In which line do You have an error? You have this information in console. It's not enough code. Where is keyup and click events binding?

Comment: This is off-topic as the error is quite simple. You have a syntax error, and it's likely that you're calling a function but you don't have the correct amount of closing braces.

Comment: Check the generated elements in dev tools, they all have `onclick="func(Dfk 6498)"` or similar; the argument inside should be a string.

Comment: Don't rely on people visiting off-site resources like fiddles. Put the [mcve] **in** the question. Runnable examples can be done with Stack Snippets (the `<>` toolbar button), but even if the MCVE is in another technology, put **all** the relevant (but minimal!) code in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Line 34 in Your fiddle. You pass string without quote. Change it to:

```
title += '<div id="element" onclick="func(\'' + ajax.results[i].original_title + '\')"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + ajax.results[i].poster_path + '" height="50" width="40" id="poster"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"';
```

Working code: http://jsfiddle.net/bkj2z39y/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to wrap ajax output in quotes,

```
title += '<div id="element" onclick="func(\"' + ajax.results[i].original_title + '\")"><img src="http://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w500' + ajax.results[i].poster_path + '" height="50" width="40" id="poster"  class="img-responsive img-thumbnail"';
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/bkj2z39y/2/